# Focus Border for DateField

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, datefield

Is there a way to Set a a focus border on a datefield when it is selected and change the border to some other colour when we lose focus from the datefield.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://flexponential.com/2010/01/24/custom-focusskin-for-spark-components-in-flex-4/) may be what you're looking for. It uses a `TextField` in its example, but it shouldn't be too hard to adapt for use with a `DateField`.

Comment: HI Jason Towne,

 I posted the question again here : "DateField Focus Skin Prob" with my codes and trials

Great if you could help. Thanks